# android spilit listview into two columns

Tags: android

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {     
                final ViewHolderList holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolderList();
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                            .inflate(R.layout.children_row_list, null);
                    position=position+2;
                    Log.d("list position::", ""+position);

                holder.img_children_view=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_children);
                holder.text_child_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_name);
                holder.text_child_month=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_month);
                holder.text_group_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_group);

                holder.img_children_view1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_children1);
                holder.text_child_name1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_name1);
                holder.text_child_month1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_month1);
                holder.text_group_name1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_group1);

                Resources r = getResources();
                float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 90, r.getDisplayMetrics());
                int pixel_height = (int) pixels;
                holder.img_children_view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80 , 80));
                holder.img_children_view1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80 , 80));

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{

                holder = (ViewHolderList) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if(position %2 == 0){
              //  System.out.println(position + " is even number.");
                holder.text_child_name.setText(children_list.get(position).getFirst_name());
                holder.text_child_name.setText(children_list.get(position).getFirst_name());
                holder.text_child_month.setText(display_month);
                holder.text_group_name.setText(children_list.get(position).getGroup_name());

                Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/com.x/y/"+children_list.get(position).getPhoto()), ConfigurationData.staffImageSize,ConfigurationData.staffImageSize);
                //holder.img_children_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
         else{
              //  System.out.println(position+ " is odd number.");                  
                holder.text_child_name1.setText(children_list.get(position).getFirst_name());
                holder.text_child_name1.setText(children_list.get(position).getFirst_name());
                holder.text_child_month1.setText(display_month);
                holder.text_group_name1.setText(children_list.get(position).getGroup_name());

                Bitmap bitmap1 = decodeFile(new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/com.x/y/"+children_list.get(position).getPhoto()), ConfigurationData.staffImageSize,ConfigurationData.staffImageSize);
                //holder.img_children_view1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
         }

            return convertView;     
        }   //closing getview
    }
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: have you considered using `TableLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, you can achieve much more by adding dynamic table rows

Comment: Use GridView with two columns

Comment: @SemyonDanilov my requirement is it must be listView ,see there is two view grid and list, this is my second option, please understand and answer me

Comment: @IssacBalaji GridView actually is a list view.

Comment: Considering the recycling method for the views inside listView (that is its main advantage) I think that is impossible to have a design like the one you desire with a single listView.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using android's `GridView` with parameter `numColumns` equals 2

[GridView @ developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: my requirement is it must be listView ,see there is two view grid and list, this is my second option, please understand and answer me

Comment: @IssacBalaji you can work with it exactly as with ListView, because GridView is derived from ListView :)

Comment: it extends AbsListView not ListView

Comment: @blackbelt so does the ListView. They share the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

Create Gridview with number of columns 2   `android:numColumns="2"`.

In xml:

```
<GridView
                    android:id="@+id/sdcard"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:numColumns="2">
                </GridView>
```

And in java code :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {     
                final ViewHolderList holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolderList();
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                            .inflate(R.layout.children_row_list, null);
                    position=position+2;
                    Log.d("list position::", ""+position);

                holder.img_children_view=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_children);
                holder.text_child_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_name);
                holder.text_child_month=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_month);
                holder.text_group_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_group);

                holder.img_children_view1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_children1);
                holder.text_child_name1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_name1);
                holder.text_child_month1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_month1);
                holder.text_group_name1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_children_group1);

                Resources r = getResources();
                float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 90, r.getDisplayMetrics());
                int pixel_height = (int) pixels;
                holder.img_children_view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80 , 80));
                holder.img_children_view1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80 , 80));

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{

                holder = (ViewHolderList) convertView.getTag();
            }

              //  System.out.println(position + " is even number.");
                holder.text_child_name.setText(children_list.get(position).getFirst_name());
                holder.text_child_name.setText(children_list.get(position).getFirst_name());
                holder.text_child_month.setText(display_month);
                holder.text_group_name.setText(children_list.get(position).getGroup_name());

                Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/com.x/y/"+children_list.get(position).getPhoto()), ConfigurationData.staffImageSize,ConfigurationData.staffImageSize);
                //holder.img_children_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            return convertView;     
        }   //closing getview
    }
```